# Как починить краш java.lang.NullPointerException at (Unknown Source)?

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение с Яндекс метрикой внутри. Туда приходит краш репорт такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что адекватного указания на то где в коде ошибка нету, у меня не на эмуляторах, не на реальных устройствах, воспроизвести ошибку не разу не получилось, а вылетает достаточно часто.
Может кто видел подобную ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело, или может есть какие-то советы как можно найти эту ошибку.

Comment: Без деобфускации не понять. Или у вас там троян от rt.com встроен? :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja про обфускацию почитаю, а про троян не знаю, код достался мне в наследство, как узнать есть ли там что-то подобное, и вычистить?

Comment: Шучу про троян :)